# Brownie Chainlink Import Error VSCode - 'File import callback not supported'

Tags: solidity, python, chainlink, brownie

[image]

The code seems to have successfully compiled, but VSCode keeps showing this error -

> "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found. File import callback not supported"

Comment: Awesome!! Can you please add the text for this so others can find this question?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I'm sorry I don't understand. Do you want me to rephrase the question where I include the error statement and other details? If yes, its done.

Comment: Nope, nevermind, you got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution.

**Step 1** - brownie pm install [ORGANIZATION]/[REPOSITORY]@[VERSION]. Do this in your terminal.
In my case, it'll be

```
brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2
brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0
```

**Step 2** - Add these in your VSCode settings,

```
  "solidity.remappings": [
    "@chainlink/=/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2",
    "@openzeppelin/=/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0"
  ]
```

All the versions are the latest as of 12-Dec-2021

Lastly to check all of your installed packages just type
`brownie pm list` in your terminal. In my case, it looks something like this.

[image]

VOILA!

Comment: Thanks to this straightforward solution!
If you're on Windows OS, and use this in the remapping.
"@chainlink/=C:/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@<your_version>"

Answer (score 1):

I did a brownie pm install for both the packages and also added following in the settings.json for Solidity

```
    {
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "0.6.0",
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"solidity.remappings": [
    "@chainlink/=/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2",
    "@openzeppelin/=/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0"
]
```

}

After doing this the brownie pm list shows the following:
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

```
    The following packages are currently installed:

     smartcontractkit
      ├─smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
      └─smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2

    OpenZeppelin
     └─OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0
```

And the same problem persists:
Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

I am using macOS.

Comment: Apologies.Missed replacing the <USERNAME> in settings.json to my username. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what fixed it for me was install another version of solidity. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qTdQNCMwk8

I was operating on v0.0.137
The guy says to install version 0.0.135 and that fixed everything for me.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

for Brownie 1.19.3 in vs code, you'll need to do the followings:

considering we have:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
```

add the following section to your project's brownie-config.yaml file

```
dependencies:
    - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.8.3
    - chiru-labs/ERC721A@4.2.3
compiler:
   solc:
      remappings:
         - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.8.3'
         - '@erc721a=chiru-labs/ERC721A@4.2.3'
```

the `chiru-labs/ERC721A@4.2.3` for example, is achieved by combining the repository name + @ + release version : [image]
also don't forget to create an access token on GitHub and set it as an environment variable like: `GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_2m7rVBTx9c88GZS...`
then you'll need to run this command in terminal `brownie compile`
brownie will automatically download those two packages and the errors will go away.
you can check to see if the packages are downloaded using `brownie pm list` command.