# File import callback not supported

Tags: chainlink, brownie

I have a YAML file configured but when I compile the code, it does not create dependencies directory and neither the json files. The sources I import mentions: File import callback not supported. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/brownie-chainlink-import-error-vscode-file-import-callback-not-supported

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if the package is correctly installed from `brownie.config.yaml` using next command

```
brownie pm list
```

If the package is missing, you need to install the package first using next command:

```
brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
```

Then compile the project again (additionally, you can use optional `-a` flag to force recompile all contracts)

```
brownie compile
```

Comment: I ran brownie pm list and I do have the package installed. Just as before, it says in the terminal that the project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at XXX. But still the JSON file is not showing in the dependencies directory.

Comment: `AggregatorV3Interface.json` should be in the `dependencies` folder once you reference it in your smart contract (for example as a state variable `AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;`). To "shut down" `File import callback not supported` VSCode error, check [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/brownie-chainlink-import-error-vscode-file-import-callback-not-supported)